# ng2-smart-table has missing dependencies completer

Tags: angular, ng2-smart-table, ng2-completer

I am using Ng2SmartTable and I have this error:

> ERROR in The target entry-point "ng2-smart-table" has missing
>   dependencies:
>    - @ akveo / ng2-completer

I have already tried the following commands and it does not work:

> 1.npm install --save ng2-smart-table
>
> 2.npm i ng2-completer --save
>
> 3.npm i rxjs-compat --save

Answer (score 6):

uninstall by using below command:-

```
npm uni @akveo/ng2-completer
```

install by using below command:-

```
npm i ng2-completer
```

It solve my problem !!

For further detail:-
https://github.com/akveo/ng2-smart-table/commit/59c3a7885591f1e003dbd67fa80844d187a89244

Answer (score 3):

just a heads up if you're upgrading ng-smart-table to v.1.7.0, there is a BREAKING change with the ng2-completer package, see https://github.com/akveo/ng2-smart-table/commit/59c3a7885591f1e003dbd67fa80844d187a89244

Answer (score 3):

```
    npm install ng2-smart-table
    npm install ng2-completer
```

If still don't work: delete node_module/ folder (install dependencies again)

```
    npm install
```

Answer (score 2):

try this.

```
npm i rxjs-compat --save
npm i @akveo/ng2-completer --save
```

See here.
https://github.com/yggg/ng2-smart-table/commit/8a4f0bb

As mentioned above, you need to be careful.

Comment: Didnt work, but I found that the following did npm i rxjs-compat --save
npm i ng2-completer --save

Answer (score 1):

Installing the dependencies makes it work in dev, but in the build prod there is a problem.

**For Angular 9+ try this:**

in your **tsconfig.app.json**, set

```
 "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": true
  }
```

its worked for me, with @akveo/ng2-completer dependency only.

Comment: Did you install @akveo/ng2-completer ?

Comment: Thanks, It works now. I was using `ng2-completer`, didn't know of `@akveo/ng2-completer` package.

But what is the significance of Ivy engine, I am not sure.
It works without the `"enableIvy": true` flag also.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

For this version

> "ng2-smart-table": "^1.6.0"

I had to run

> npm install --save ng2-completer

because version 1.6.0 use `require('ng2-completer')` instead of `require('@akveo/ng2-completer')`

Answer (score 1):

at the moment, i also installed both

```
ng2-smart-table at 1.7.2
@akveo/ng2-completer at 9.0.1
```

i found a problem when used ng2-smart-table at 1.7.2

so, i downgraded ng2-smart-table to 1.6.0.

it seems work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue while trying to install  **ng2-smart-table**

In ng2-smart-table the **CompleterService** is imported in the following way

> import { CompleterService } from '@akveo/ng2-completer';

But if we open ng2-completer from node_modules you can see the ng2-completer is not within the **'@akveo'** folder

So just create a new folder in node_module and rename it as **@akveo** and copy the  **ng2-completer** files into **@akevo** folder

Now  open package.json , package.lock.json and change  **ng2-completer** to **@akveo/ng2-completer** and restart the server

it will be working fine

Thanks

Comment: You should not change the content of node_modules directory by hand.

Comment: could you tell me the reason but my project runs without any problem @A.ElIdrissi

Comment: @ Vignesh A. As you know node_modules directory is managed automatically by npm.

Answer (score 0):

For my Angular 11 project, I got it solved by installing following two packages to get ng2-smart-table running:

`npm i ng2-smart-table --save`

`npm i ng2-completer --save`

Answer (score -1):

Try this:
`npm install ng2-completer --save-dev`

More details are available [here](https://github.com/akveo/ng2-smart-table/issues/845#issuecomment-408239379)