# Angular smart table not working after migration from angular-5 to angular-9

Tags: angular

I am new to angular and when I migrate from angular-5 to angular-9 version, getting ng2-smart-table error during compilation time.
[image: 1]

Comment: The answer is here as below: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61027486/ng2-smart-table-has-missing-dependencies-completer

Comment: have you solve this ?

Comment: yes, its got resolved  by installing below dependencies,

Comment: npm i rxjs-compat --save
npm i @akveo/ng2-completer --save